# Google Charts says "No Data" using array.push

Tags: charts, polymer, google-visualization, polymer-1.0

Trying to embed a google-pie-chart widget into a custom widget and I'm apparently not formatting the data correctly.

**HTML Reference**

```
<widget-piechart-daily 
    dataid="ConsentDecisionsToday" 
    charttitle="Consent Decisions Today">
</widget-piechart-daily>
```

**Widget HTML**

```
<template>
    <google-chart id$="piechart{{dataid}}"
                  type='pie'
                  options$='{"title": "{{charttitle}}"}'
                  cols='[{"label":"Decision", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Count", "type":"number"}]'
                  rows$='{{values}}'>
    </google-chart>
</template>
```

**Polymer() params**

```
    ...
    values: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {return []}
    },
    charttitle: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
    },
    ...
```

**Widget Javascript**

```
    registerCallback(this.dataid, function (data) {
        var y = data.data[0];
        self.values = [];
        //var z = y[Object.keys(y)[0]];
        for (var key in y) {
            if (y.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var z = y[key];
                i = z;
                if (key != 'Today'){
                    var i = parseFloat(Math.round(z * 100) / 100).toFixed(self.decimals);
                    self.values.push([key,i])
                }
            }
        }
        self.isloading = false;
        console.log(self.values);
    });
```

The callback is for a pubnub stream.  When I log `self.values` it looks like this:

[image]

But here is how the chart renders:

[image]

How can I modify `self.values.push([key,i])` to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all, but that "No Data" message does not look like the one used by the Google Visualization API. That message appears in a little red box. Perhaps this is coming from your polymer component? Also worth noting that your number value appears as a string in the log output. Maybe convert that to a number type and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a [Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart),

*Column 0* should be a `'string'`
*Column 1* should be a `'number'`

however, a `'string'` is being used for *Column 1*
(result of `toFixed`)

```
if (key != 'Today'){
    var i = parseFloat(Math.round(z * 100) / 100).toFixed(self.decimals);
    self.values.push([key,i])
}
```

try using a number instead

```
if (key != 'Today'){
    var i = parseFloat(Math.round(z * 100) / 100);
    self.values.push([key,i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Polymer's [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#work-with-arrays) to modify the array and to notify the binding system of the change:

```
for (var key in y) {
  ...
  self.push('values', [key, i]);
}
```

Comment: Same result. Even the console output looks identical.